# Is it possible to associate same codebehind to multiple classes in silverlight like in flash

Tags: silverlight, flash

In flash one can point to a file on disk to associate the form with a class which name can be different from the form name so that you can multiple forms to the same class.

In Silverlight is it possible somehow including by hacking vs studio project xml file by hand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's performed using inheritence. You can define all you need in a base control, and derived controls use this code. For example you want define event handler that will be used for all your controls:

Define the event handler in the base class - BaseControl.xaml.cs

```
namespace SilverlightApp
{
    public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
    {
        public BaseControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // The event handler that used by derived classes
        protected void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             // your implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

BaseControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApp.BaseControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <!-- your implementation here if needed -->
</UserControl>
```

MyControl1.xaml.cs - defines new control inherited from theBaseControl. You just need to specify the base class

```
namespace SilverlightApp
{
    public partial class MyControl1 : BaseControl
    {
        public MyControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MyControl1.xaml

```
<local:BaseControl x:Class="SilverlightApp.MyControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <!-- button uses event handler from the base class -->
        <Button Content="My button" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</local:BaseControl>
```

Hope it what you have meant.